# Get element by id and change its sibling value

Tags: javascript, siblings

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr id="1">
        <td id="a">aa</td>
        <td>bb</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("1").children[1].innerHTML="newB"  // it works as expected.     
document.getElementById("a").nextSibling.innerHTML="newB" // it does not work.
```

How can I change `td id="a"` sibling value using 2nd approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nextElementSibling`

```
document.getElementById("a").nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "newB";
```

`nextSibling` will select the empty `textNode` as you can see in the following demo

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("a").nextSibling);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td id="a">aa</td>
    <td>bb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can see that `nextSibling` will work as expected when you have no space between the elements. So, it'll not select the empty *textNode*.

```js
document.getElementById("a").nextSibling.innerHTML = "newB";
```

```html
<table>
    <tr id="1">
        <td id="a">aa</td><td>bb</td> <!-- No space, it works! -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't know where to click accepted. But your code works.

Answer (score 0):

It is because, the next sibling of the `td` could be a text node, you need the next element sibling.

You can use the [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) property

```js
document.getElementById("a").nextElementSibling.innerHTML = "newB";
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="1">
    <td id="a">aa</td>
    <td>bb</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note: supported in [IE 9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling#Specification)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes.. should be just `nextElementSibling.innerHTML`